# How retain_grad() in pytorch works? I found its position changes the grad result

Tags: python, pytorch

in a simple test in pytorch, I want to see grad in a non-leaf tensor, so I use retain_grad():

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.zeros((10))
gt = torch.zeros((10))

y[0] = a
y[1] = y[0] * 2
y.retain_grad()

loss = torch.sum((y-gt) ** 2)
loss.backward()
print(y.grad)
```

it gives me a normal output:

```
tensor([2., 4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

but when I use retain grad() before y[1] and after y[0] is assigned:

```
import torch
a = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
y = torch.zeros((10))
gt = torch.zeros((10))

y[0] = a
y.retain_grad()
y[1] = y[0] * 2

loss = torch.sum((y-gt) ** 2)
loss.backward()
print(y.grad)
```

now the output changes to:

```
tensor([10.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

I can't understand the result at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay so what's going on is really weird.

What `.retain_grad()` essentially does is convert any non-leaf tensor into a leaf tensor, such that it contains a `.grad` attribute (since by default, pytorch computes gradients to leaf tensors only).

Hence, in your first example, after calling `y.retain_grad()`, it basically converted `y` into a leaf tensor with an accessible `.grad` attribute.

However, in your second example, you initially converted the entire `y` tensor into a leaf tensor; **then**, you created a non-leaf tensor `(y[1])` **within** your leaf tensor `(y)`, which is what caused the confusion.

```
y = torch.zeros((10))  # y is a non-leaf tensor

y[0] = a  # y[0] is a non-leaf tensor
y.retain_grad()  # y is a leaf tensor (including y[1])
y[1] = y[0] * 2  # y[1] is a non-leaf tensor, BUT y[0], y[2], y[3], ..., y[9] are all leaf tensors!
```

The confusing part is:

`y[1]` **after** calling `y.retain_grad()` **is** now a leaf tensor with a `.grad` attribute. However, `y[1]` **after** the computation `(y[1] = y[0] * 2)` is now **not** a leaf tensor with a `.grad` attribute; it is now treated as a new non-leaf variable/tensor.

Therefore, when calling `loss.backward()`, the Chain rule of the `loss` w.r.t `y`, and particularly looking at the Chain rule of the `loss` w.r.t leaf `y[1]` now looks something like this:

---

[image: Chain rule]

Comment: `retain_grad()` does not convert to leaf tensor. You can verify that by printing `y.is_leaf`. Being a leaf is different from retaining a grad. Simply leaf tensors always retain grad, while non-leaf tensors by default don't.